# R shiny work with input data (excel, csv)

Tags: r, excel, csv, input, shiny

I have 2 problems to work with an input csv or excel file while using Shiny.

First I have to use two commands to input a csv or an exel file, but these file names are not allowed to have the same names (I tried a if or token example but it dont work fine). Is there a possibility that it is automatically recognized which type of file he should load?

The second problem is, that now I want to work with these input file and I read that in the server function, we can access the uploaded files via input$name. But it don´t work...

Add: the title=div(img(src=D/Pfad"), dont work, too. But this is not so important

here is my code:

ui

```
    library(shiny)
library(readxl)
library(DT)
library(markdown)
ui <- fluidPage(
navbarPage(title=div(img(src=D/Pfad"), "Willkommen"),
           tabPanel("Input",
                    sidebarLayout(
                      sidebarPanel(
                        fileInput('file1', 'Einlesen'  ),
                        checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
                        radioButtons("sep", "Separator",
                                     choices = c(Semicolon = ";",
                                       Comma = ",",

                                                 Tab = "\t"),
                                     selected = ";")
                      ),
                      mainPanel(
                        tabsetPanel(
                          tabPanel("Data",
                                   h4("Data"),
                                   tableOutput("input_file_csv"),
                                   tableOutput('input_file_xlsx')
                                   #this two commands should be one, but it works

                                   ),
                          tabPanel("Summary",
                                   tableOutput("summary") #this doesn´t work because the load input Data don´t work in the server
                                   ),
                          tabPanel("New")
                        )
                      )
                    )
           )))
```

server:

```
   library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(markdown)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  # I want to get one input file with name input_file, but it seems that it is not allowed to have the same names? Why?
    output$input_file_csv<- renderTable({
      inFile <- input$file1

  if (is.null(inFile)){
    return(NULL)
  }
  a <- read.table(inFile$datapath, sep = input$sep, header = input$header)
})

output$input_file_xlsx <- renderTable({
  inFile <- input$file1

  if(is.null(inFile))
    return(NULL)
  file.rename(inFile$datapath,
              paste(inFile$datapath, ".xlsx", sep=""))
  read_excel(paste(inFile$datapath, ".xlsx", sep=""), 1)
  })

output$summary <- renderTable({
  library(tidyverse)

  # load input Data don´t work
  data <- data.frame(input$file1)

  # some work with the input file
  summary <- data %>%
    gather(name,value) %>%  # reshape datset
    count(name, value)      # count combinations
        summary
     })
  })
```

I hope someone can help me... I was so proud to get an input file but I don´t find any example that work with it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you accepting user-uploaded data files, or are you using pre-defined, server-side data files?

Comment: I want to accepting user-uploaded data files.

Comment: this single quote is a typo or a problem with your code?
 `(title=div(img(src=D/Pfad")`

Comment: This typo is a problem, too. The image is not displayed, but a question mark is there to see instead. At the top of the ui you can find the Code: navbarPage(title=div(img(src=D/Pfad"), "Willkommen"). D/Pfad should be the path, R can find my image which should be displayed. Do you understand?